# Store an array into MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays

I need to store two values ​​in the same column. These are the code and name, separated by a hyphen. How can I do this using this array?

`'name'=> $data['code']['name']`

I read about serialization, but I do not see how to implement it here.

```
  public function addProduct($code, $name,  $photo, $data = array())
    {           
        if($photo == NULL) {
            // Product data
            $productData = array(
                'code'                  => $data['code'],
                'name'                  => $data['name'],
                'category_id'           => $data['category_id'],
                'subcategory_id'        => $data['subcategory_id'], 
            );
        } else {
            // Product data
            $productData = array(
                'code'                  => $data['code'],
                'name'                  => $data['name'],
                'category_id'           => $data['category_id'],
                'subcategory_id'        => $data['subcategory_id'],
                'image'                 => $photo
            );
        }

        if($this->db->insert('products', $productData)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What language is your code in (tag it appropriately?)

Comment: `I need to store two values ​​in the same column` Don't do that. Use two columns instead. Each column should correspond to one and only one piece of information.

Comment: and storing arrays is efficiently done when storing array in rows.

Comment: Make sure your information like 'code','name','category_id'.. should be columns of the table and store data according.

Comment: This is a coodeingiter platform. I need to store the two variables together in the same row/record, in column name or other, like "code"-"name".

Isn't possible?

Comment: Satish Shinde, they are columns, and the goal is pic two variables at the same time and save it togheter maybe to another column. Is easier for me to catch it and then export it to the table, because I do not feel very comfortable with codeigniter.. I supose this is possible. But I don't know how!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you want this:

```
'name' => serialize(array('code'=>$data['code'], 'name'=>$data['name']))
```

Then to retrieve it you can simply

```
$data = unserialize($res['name']); 
echo $data['code']."-".$data['name'];
```

You can also use `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` in lou of `serialize()` and `unserialize()`. The benefit of using JSON is you can decode it with other languages like JavaScript whereas seialize() is a PHP-specific function.

Comment: Adelphia this really do what I want!

Now I am dealing with other problem in retrieve the data   because it includes joins... 
Time to try to overcome that issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 methods in CodeIgniter to insert data in the database.

**1st Method: normal SQL query**

```
public function addProduct($code, $name,  $photo, $data = array()){         
    $sql = "";
    if($photo == null){
        // Product data
        $d_code = isset($data['code']) ? $this->db->escape($data['code']) : '';
        $d_name = isset($data['name']) ? $this->db->escape($data['name']) : '';
        $d_category_id = isset($data['category_id']) ? $this->db->escape($data['category_id']) : '';
        $d_subcategory_id = isset($data['subcategory_id']) ? $this->db->escape($data['subcategory_id']) : '';
        $sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (code, name, category_id, subcategory_id) ";
        $sql .= "VALUES ('" . $d_code . "', '" . $d_name . "', '" . $d_category_id . "', '" . $d_subcategory_id . "')";
    } else {
        // Product data
        $d_code = isset($data['code']) ? $this->db->escape($data['code']) : '';
        $d_name = isset($data['name']) ? $this->db->escape($data['name']) : '';
        $d_category_id = isset($data['category_id']) ? $this->db->escape($data['category_id']) : '';
        $d_subcategory_id = isset($data['subcategory_id']) ? $this->db->escape($data['subcategory_id']) : '';
        $d_image = isset($photo) ? $this->db->escape($photo) : '';
        $sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (code, name, category_id, subcategory_id, image) ";
        $sql .= "VALUES ('" . $d_code . "', '" . $d_name . "', '" . $d_category_id . "', '" . $d_subcategory_id . "', '" . $d_image . "')";
    }
    $this->db->query($sql);
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**2nd Method: ActiveRecord**

```
public function addProduct($code, $name,  $photo, $data = array()){         
    if($photo == null){
        // Product data
        $d_code = isset($data['code']) ? $this->db->escape($data['code']) : '';
        $d_name = isset($data['name']) ? $this->db->escape($data['name']) : '';
        $d_category_id = isset($data['category_id']) ? $this->db->escape($data['category_id']) : '';
        $d_subcategory_id = isset($data['subcategory_id']) ? $this->db->escape($data['subcategory_id']) : '';
        $dataArr = array(
           'code' => $d_code,
           'name' => $d_name,
           'category_id' => $d_category_id,
           'subcategory_id' => $d_subcategory_id
        );
    } else {
        // Product data
        $d_code = isset($data['code']) ? $this->db->escape($data['code']) : '';
        $d_name = isset($data['name']) ? $this->db->escape($data['name']) : '';
        $d_category_id = isset($data['category_id']) ? $this->db->escape($data['category_id']) : '';
        $d_subcategory_id = isset($data['subcategory_id']) ? $this->db->escape($data['subcategory_id']) : '';
        $d_image = isset($photo) ? $this->db->escape($photo) : '';
        $dataArr = array(
           'code' => $d_code,
           'name' => $d_name,
           'category_id' => $d_category_id,
           'subcategory_id' => $d_subcategory_id,
           'image' => $d_image
        );
    }
    $this->db->insert('mytable', $dataArr); 
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Notes**

Keep in mind that in both ways you should have the exact structure in the MySQL database. Otherwise you'll have errors such as "column not found" etc.

On another hand, you can't store an array in MySQL, but you can store a comma-separated value (CSV) string, although it's not recommended at all:

```
$dataArr = array(
    $d_code,
    $d_name,
    $d_category_id,
    $d_subcategory_id
);
$csv = implode(",", $dataArr);
```

This solution will cause problems if any of the data provided contains a comma.

Why you shouldn't store a CSV in a MySQL row:

- every piece of information should be treated and saved on its own.
- searching within the data will be impossible using MySQL.
- forget about "indexing". It's useless in this case. Also, forget about query optimization.
- you're looking for a specific piece of information, then you should probably query all the table and loop over this information to get the data you're looking for.
- no developers will understand your move.
- it'll definitely cause you problems in CodeIgniter, especially in the ActiveRecord methods.
- it's really easy to insert/select/update/delete info from the database in CodeIgniter: [link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/examples.html)
- if it's the first time you're working on CodeIgniter, then take a few more minutes reading the docs and learn it well. Doing awful hacks won't help anyone and especially you, because you'll end up with bugs and a messy code.

Comment: Thanks Wissam El-Kik!
I can't vote up cause I do not have enough reputation but a huge thank by the explanation!
Best regards